# I have a limit whose variable is both within the integral and in the integral boundaries. May I split it?

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

More concretely, I have the integral

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\left(0,\frac{n}{2}\right)}x^2e^x\left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^nd\lambda(x)$$

It is clear that this is the same as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\left(0,\frac{n}{2}\right)}x^2e^xe^{-2x}d\lambda(x)$$

Which them simplifies to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\left(0,\frac{n}{2}\right)}x^2e^{-x}d\lambda(x)$$
What are the exact rules that apply to such limits? Do I need to mention them?

Comment: I dont see that $(1-\frac{2x}{n})^n=e^{-2x}$

Comment: $$lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{-a}{n})^n=e^{-a}$$

Comment: Then you would have to justify swapping the limit and integral, perhaps by lebesgues dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: You can insert the characteristic function $1_{[0,n/2]}$ into the integral and then integrate from $0$ to $\infty$ right from the start. In this way you don't have to bother about the $n$-dependent boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind this integral is to apply the [dominated convergence theorem for measurable functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). First of all define $f(x) := 1_{[0,\frac{n}{2}]}x^2e^x\left( 1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n$. We note that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} 1_{[0,\frac{n}{2}]}x^2e^x\left( 1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n = 1_{[0,\infty]}x^2e^xe^{-2x} = 1_{[0,\infty]}x^2e^{-x}=:f$$

$f$ is measurable since is a composition of measurable functions.
Moreover

$$|f(x)| = |1_{[0,\frac{n}{2}]}x^2e^x\left( 1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^n|\le 1_{[0,\infty]}x^2e^xe^{-2x}=x^2e^{-x}=:g(x)$$

and

$$\int g(x)d\lambda = \int1_{[0,\infty]}x^2e^{-x}d\lambda=\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-x}d\lambda=2\lt\infty$$

Now we are allowed to apply the dominated convergence theorem since all the conditions needed are satisfied and we get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\left(0,\frac{n}{2}\right)}x^2e^x\left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^nd\lambda(x)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1_{[0,\frac{n}{2}]}x^2e^x\left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^nd\lambda(x)$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}1_{[0,\frac{n}{2}]}x^2e^x\left(1-\frac{2x}{n}\right)^nd\lambda(x)=\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-x}d\lambda=2$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the $n$ dependence is in the integral parameter, I think we can just use:

$\int_{(0,\frac{n}{2})}x^2e^x(1-\frac{2x}{n})^nd\lambda\leq\int_{(0,\frac{n}{2})}x^2e^{-x}d\lambda(x)$ Now try integration by parts and then take the limit.

Integration by parts gives us $\int_{(0,\frac{n}{2})}x^2e^{-x}d\lambda(x)=-e^{\frac{-n}{2}}\frac{n^2}{4}-e^{\frac{-n}{2}}n-2e^{\frac{-n}{2}}+2\rightarrow 2$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: Though I don't know what impact the integral parameters depending on $n$ has

Comment: Why do you take the limit two times? You can't do that..

Comment: I haven't, I've just used an inequality with the exponential

Comment: You have taken the limit inside the integral and then you have evaluated another limit which doesn't exist. Moreover the function$x^2$ is not integrable for every $n$ since for $n \to \infty$ the interval has infinity measure and the function is strictly increasing on that interval

Comment: I forgot to remove the part about lebesgue theorem. I have used the fact that $(1-\frac{x}{2n})^n\leq e^{-x}$ to remove the $n$ dependence from within the integral